# Assigning ActiveCell value to a variable preserving 0 prefix

Tags: excel, vba

I have started to program a macro where I would need to assign a part number (PN) of a product to a variable for a later search:

```
Sheets("Panel").Activate
Range("E10").Select
PN_value = ActiveCell.Value
```

The above statements work fine, except in the case of zero prefix ( i.e. 01200946 ) the assigned value to the variable cuts the first zero and then the compare of the read out PNs in a loop with this variable is not working properly.

I have found some advice for hard formatting as "00000000" for similar cases but unfortunatelly my master data file does not contain PNs with all the same lengths and in the future some PNs might have mixed char&num format. So if possible I would need some way to assign the exact value of the cell to the variable rather than force in advance some fixed format.

Comment: try `PN_value = Sheets("Panel").Range("E10").Text`. Also ensure that `PN_value` is a `String` type variable.

Comment: Thank you very much Scott, It works fine in this way!